# Exception when receiving SOAP message

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, soap, jax-ws

I'm using jax-ws 2.2.7 to produce a web service. The operation signature is:

```
@WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "setInvocationAddress", targetNamespace = "http://services.choreos.org/", className = "org.choreos.services.SetInvocationAddress")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "setInvocationAddressResponse", targetNamespace = "http://services.choreos.org/", className = "org.choreos.services.SetInvocationAddressResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://services.choreos.org/ShopEntrance/setInvocationAddressRequest", output = "http://services.choreos.org/ShopEntrance/setInvocationAddressResponse")
    public void setInvocationAddress(
            @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "") String arg0,
            @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "") String arg1,
            @WebParam(name = "arg2", targetNamespace = "") List<String> arg2);
```

This web service is running on Tomcat 6 with java 7.

I have sent the following SOAP message to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pre="http://services.choreos.org/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <pre:setInvocationAddress>
                    <arg0>CD-shopentrance-marketingapplication</arg0>
                    <arg1>marketingapplication</arg1>
                    <arg2>http://localhost:8080/marketingapplication/marketingapplication</arg2>
                </pre:setInvocationAddress>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In localhost environment it works. But not in production.

When things did not work, I got the following stack trace at the server side (tomcat log):

```
May 24, 2015 11:29:04 PM   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
    SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,90]
    com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,90]
            at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:317)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:344)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$400(HttpAdapter.java:100)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:634)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:264)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:218)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,90]
            at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:326)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:99)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:169)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:104)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:202)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:338)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:156)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:312)
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
     at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,90]
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3058)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2941)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleRootElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2078)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2058)
            at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1117)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:96)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:80)
            ... 28 more
```

Someone has some idea of what happens?

Tks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you cannot have blank target namespace.
It should be:

```
@WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "http://services.choreos.org/")
```

Seems like JAX-WS generated the wrong annotation or you have some problem with your WSDL/XSD.